# enabling proguard does not slows the APK generation

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-proguard

I have an Android application .I am making a release build.  Earlier I used to generate signed APK using Eclipse with proguard enabled. It used to take 4 minutes to generated my APK.

Now I have moved to Android Studio. Now when I try to generate signed APK, it only takes 4 seconds. I think its not proper.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }
}
```

this are the lines I have added in my build.gradle file to enable proguard.
I am generating the signed APK using following steps:

Menu -> Build -> Generate Signed APK... -> selected my module -> Added Keystore Path , password, key alias , password -> selected build type as release ->finish.
it finished in 4 seconds and generated the APK .

I want to know why 4 minutes in Eclipse and only 4 seconds in Android Studio.
Am I missing something?

Comment: try installing released apk on device if it was built wrong then probably it should not get installed on device

Comment: @VivekMishra it got installed proeprly.

Comment: then it should not be missing anything

Comment: @VivekMishra is there any way to be sure of that ?

Comment: upload it on play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Like clean Build was required before start generating the signed APK. 
As i do clean build , and then generate the APK. It works properly.